# Group By 'MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm'

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have records of scores that I group by the date,pid,bidc and use SUM to aggregate the scores.The original field type is datetime. By grouping by date, I am getting incorrect aggregates because I have multiple sets in a given hour-min for a given day.What is the correct way to handle this and aggregate by 'MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm'

```
 var scores = from ts in _context.Scores
              select ts;

 List<ScoreAgg> aggScores = scores.GroupBy(p => new { p.create_dt.Date, p.pid, p.bidc }).Select(g => new ScoreAgg()
            {
                pid = g.Key.pid,
                bidc = g.Key.bidc,
                score = g.Sum(s => s.weight),
                create_dt = g.Key.Date
            }).ToList<ScoreAgg>();
```

Comment: You are not grouping by date, you are grouping by date, pid and bidc. That could already cause your problem. If not, in the GroupBy call, instead of `p.create_dt.Date` use `p.create_dt.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm")`

Comment: No,I am using the Date part of the create_dt p.create_dt.Date and that is causing the incorrect aggregates.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten groupby .ToString(...) is an awesome way to destroy index. Use an indexed calculated column instead

Comment: How about creating new DateTime? `p.create_dt.Date.Date.AddHours(p.create_dt.Hours).AddMinutes(p.create_dt.Minutes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DbFunction.CreateDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.createdatetime(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(System.Nullable%7BSystem.Int32%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.Int32%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.Int32%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.Int32%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.Int32%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.Double%7D)) to build date without seconds:

```
scores.GroupBy(p => new {
  Date = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(p.create_dt.Year, p.create_dt.Month, p.create_dt.Day, p.create_dt.Hour, p.create_dt.Minute, second:null)
  p.pid, 
  p.bidc
 })
```

Comment: Thanks. I used new Datetime instead of DBFunction, like this new DateTime(p.create_dt.Year, p.create_dt.Month, p.create_dt.Day, p.create_dt.Hour, p.create_dt.Minute,0). Is there any reason to use DBFunction?

Comment: @inquisitive_mind `DbFunctions` will be executed on server side. `new DateTim` can be executed only on client side and it cannot be converted to SQL query

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making a computed column on the table like

```
DateOnly AS CONVERT(date, [Date])
```

`GroupBy(p => new { p.create_dt.DateOnly, p.pid, p.bidc })`

and index DateOnly column to make aggregate faster. if you just do a convert inside your groupby clause Sql will not use the index defined on Date at all.